# NInject equivalent of Autofac's AsClosedTypesOf

Tags: c#, ninject, autofac

What is the NInject equivalent of the following code that uses Autofac:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = ...;
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(OpenGeneric<>))
                                       .As<IAnInterface>();

var resolved = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IAnInterface>>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Ninject 3.0.0-rc3 you can use

```
kernel.Bind(
      x => x.FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom(typeof(BaseService<>)).WhichAreGeneric()
            .BindToAllInterfaces());
```

Depending on your requirements you can probably remove the `WhichAreGeneric` statement. `.SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom(typeof(BaseService<>)).WhichAreGeneric()` selects the classes to which a binding is created.

Conventions ensures that the interface and the implementation class must have the same open type arguments. E.g. In case

```
interface IBar<T1, T2>
interface IBaz<T>
interface IFoo
class Bar<T1, T2> : IBar<T1, T2>, IBaz<T1>, IFoo
class Foo : IBar<int, int>, IFoo
```

`IBar<T1, T2>` is the only valid interface for `Bar<T1, T2>`. But for Foo both `IBar<int, int>, IFoo` are valid.

Comment: OK, thanks for your quick reply (I'll stick to Autofac for the moment)

Comment: This is now possible using Ninject 3.0.0-rc3

Comment: This is a release candidate. If no severe bug is detected it will become the final. So it depends on how fast I get enough positive feedback.